Java Vector API (Mandelbrot calculation)
I was experimenting with benchmarking a serial version of mandelbrot calulation vs a version using the vector API.
Here's the code:
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int width = 1920;
        int height = 1080;
        int max_iterations = 5000;

        final int[] default_palette = {-16774636, -16510682, -16246472, -15982517, -15718307, -15454353, -15190398, -14860652, -14596442, -14332487, -14068277, -13804323, -13474576, -13673506, -13806644, -14005318, -14138456, -14337130, -14470267, -14668941, -14802079, -15000753, -15133891, -15332565, -15465702, -14350567, -13169639, -12054248, -10873320, -9758185, -8642793, -7461866, -6280938, -5165803, -3984875, -2869484, -1688556, -2869485, -3984622, -5099759, -6214896, -7330033, -8445170, -9560563, -10675700, -11790837, -12905974, -14021111, -15136247, -14018808, -12901369, -11783674, -10666234, -9548795, -8431356, -7313661, -6196221, -5078526, -3961087, -2843648, -1660416, -2842880, -3959807, -5142270, -6259197, -7441660, -8558332, -9740795, -10857722, -12040185, -13157112, -14339575, -15456246, -15586039, -15715832, -15780089, -15909882, -16039675, -16103931, -16233724, -16363517, -16427774, -16557567, -16687360, -16751616, -16753664, -16755455, -16691966, -16693757, -16630268, -16632060, -16634107, -16570362, -16572409, -16508664, -16510711, -16446966, -15331573, -14216179, -13100785, -11985392, -10869998, -9754604, -8639467, -7523817, -6408423, -5293030, -4177636, -2996706, -3653601, -4310495, -4967389, -5624284, -6281178, -6937816, -7594711, -8251605, -8908499, -9565394, -10287824, -10878926, -10418377, -9892035, -9431485, -8905143, -8444593, -7918507, -7457702, -6931360, -6470810, -5944468, -5483918, -4957576, -5942159, -6926742, -7911324, -8895907, -9880490, -10864816, -11849399, -12833982, -13818564, -14803147, -15787730, -16772056, -16639947, -16442302, -16310192, -16112547, -15980438, -15848073, -15650427, -15452782, -15320672, -15123027, -14990918, -14793016, -14990919, -15123286, -15321189, -15453556, -15651459, -15783826, -15981729, -16114096, -16311999, -16444366, -16642525};

        BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        BufferedImage image2 = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

        double size = 8.94069671630859375e-8;
        double xCenter = 0.32199330953881166728080768;
        double yCenter = 0.48903524968773126602172851;

        int image_size = Math.min(width, height);

        double coefx = width == image_size ? 0.5 : (1 + (width - (double)height) / height) * 0.5;
        double coefy = height == image_size ? 0.5 : (1 + (height - (double)width) / width) * 0.5;

        double size_2_x = size * coefx;
        double size_2_y = size * coefy;
        double temp_size_image_size_x = size / image_size;
        double temp_size_image_size_y = size / image_size;

        double temp_xcenter_size = xCenter - size_2_x;
        double temp_ycenter_size = yCenter + size_2_y;

        int[] rgbs = ((DataBufferInt) image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
        int[] rgbs2 = ((DataBufferInt) image2.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();

        long time = System.nanoTime();

        for(int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
                double zre = 0;
                double zim = 0;
                double cre = temp_xcenter_size + temp_size_image_size_x * x;
                double cim = temp_ycenter_size - temp_size_image_size_y * y;
                double zre_sqr;
                double zim_sqr;
                double norm_sqr;

                int iteration;
                for(iteration = 0; iteration < max_iterations; iteration++) {
                    zre_sqr = zre * zre;
                    zim_sqr = zim * zim;
                    norm_sqr = zre_sqr + zim_sqr;
                    if(norm_sqr >= 4) {
                        break;
                    }
                    double temp = zre_sqr - zim_sqr + cre;
                    zim = zre * zim * 2 + cim;
                    zre = temp;
                }

                if(iteration == max_iterations) {
                    rgbs[y * width + x] = Color.BLACK.getRGB();
                }
                else {
                    rgbs[y * width + x] = default_palette[iteration % default_palette.length];
                }

            }
        }

        System.out.println(System.nanoTime() - time);

        time = System.nanoTime();

        VectorSpecies<Double> DOUBLE_SPECIES = DoubleVector.SPECIES_PREFERRED;

        int laneCount = DOUBLE_SPECIES.length();

        double[] re = new double[laneCount];
        double[] im = new double[laneCount];

        int length = DOUBLE_SPECIES.loopBound(rgbs.length);

        int[] iters = new int[laneCount];

        for(int p = 0; p < length; p += laneCount) {

            for(int i = 0; i < laneCount; i++) {
                int y = (p + i) / width;
                int x = (p + i) % width;
                re[i] = temp_xcenter_size + temp_size_image_size_x * x;
                im[i] = temp_ycenter_size - temp_size_image_size_y * y;
                iters[i] = -1;
            }


            DoubleVector creals = DoubleVector.fromArray(DOUBLE_SPECIES, re, 0);
            DoubleVector cimaginarys = DoubleVector.fromArray(DOUBLE_SPECIES, im, 0);
            DoubleVector zreals = DoubleVector.zero(DOUBLE_SPECIES);
            DoubleVector zimaginarys = DoubleVector.zero(DOUBLE_SPECIES);

            DoubleVector zreals_sqr;
            DoubleVector zimaginarys_sqr;
            DoubleVector norms;
            VectorMask<Double> maskNorm;

            for(int iteration = 0; iteration < max_iterations; iteration++) {

                zreals_sqr = zreals.mul(zreals);
                zimaginarys_sqr = zimaginarys.mul(zimaginarys);
                norms = zreals_sqr.add(zimaginarys_sqr);
                maskNorm = norms.lt(4.0);


                if(!maskNorm.allTrue()) {
                    setIter(maskNorm, laneCount, iteration, iters);
                }

                if(!maskNorm.anyTrue()) {
                    break;
                }


                var temp_reals = zreals_sqr.sub(zimaginarys_sqr).add(creals);
                zimaginarys = zreals.mul(zimaginarys).mul(2).add(cimaginarys);
                zreals = temp_reals;

            }

            for(int i = 0; i < laneCount; i++) {
                if(iters[i] == -1) {
                    iters[i] = max_iterations;
                }

                setPixel(iters[i], p + i, max_iterations, rgbs2, default_palette);
            }
            
        }

        for (int p = length; p < rgbs.length; p++) {
            //Handle the remaining
            //Todo
        }

        System.out.println(System.nanoTime() - time);

        try {
            ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File("out.png"));
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {}

        try {
            ImageIO.write(image2, "png", new File("out2.png"));
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {}

    }

    private static void setIter(VectorMask<Double> maskNorm, int laneCount, int iteration, int[] iters) {
        long mask = maskNorm.toLong();
        for(int i = 0; i < laneCount; i++) {
            if(iters[i] == -1 && (mask & 1) == 0) {
                iters[i] = iteration;
            }
            mask >>>= 1;
        }
    }

    private static void setPixel(int iteration, int index, int max_iterations, int[] rgbs, int[] default_palette) {
        if(iteration == max_iterations) {
            rgbs[index] = Color.BLACK.getRGB();
        }
        else {
            rgbs[index] = default_palette[iteration % default_palette.length];
        }
    }
}

For some reason the serial code outperforms the vector API version.
Keep in mind the the vector API version does not handle the final pixels correctly, its still in todo mode.
Am I doing something wrong here?
The times that I get on my laptop in nanoseconds is:
2718696300 for the serial
3202282700 for the vector API
Also Ideally I would like to stop updating the zre, zim values when the corresponding lane has escaped from the bailout criterion.
var temp_reals = zreals_sqr.sub(zimaginarys_sqr, maskNorm).add(creals, maskNorm);
zimaginarys = zreals.mul(zimaginarys, maskNorm).mul(2, maskNorm).add(cimaginarys, maskNorm);
zreals = temp_reals;
I used something like that, but this was even slower.
Serial mandebrot calulation is faster than the Vector API equivalent.


Read How do I write a correct micro-benchmark in Java? 2) Creating a humongous method is the worst thing you can do to the JIT/Runtime optimizer. Create reasonable software design and the performance will follow. Separate these two different approaches and split them further into meaningful methods.


I have refactored the code into modules and also run for a couple for samples (20)
Serial: 2.68203515E9
AVX: 1.133907695E9
Speedup: 2.3653028917843266

The individual samples for serial were: 2721396300 2729566300 2684527700 2710760200 2673580000 2672368400 2672480500 2673540100 2672269100 2672105100 2672504000 2671700400 2672448600 2671990400 2703527700 2672525300 2672660400 2673165800 2674846100 2672740600

The individual samples for AVX were: 3251201600 2769121700 922963100 927474200 925873400 925462500 927450400 925035200 924325500 927866400 924824200 924766400 926393400 923195400 925366700 925958100 924280200 926307800 925184100 925103600

So it seems that AVX is faster but it needs some time to crank up?

which platform is this running on, more specifically, does its hardware support,  and is it running vector instructions? From the javadoc of jdk.incubator.vector: "Performance notes
This package depends on the runtime's ability to dynamically compile vector operations into optimal vector hardware instructions. There is a default scalar implementation for each operation which is used if the operation cannot be compiled to vector instructions."

Windows 10, my machine supports avx2, so the lanecount for doubles is 4, 4 * 64 = 256

The vector API definitely requires the JIT to kick in. You could help it with fine tuning, by forcing compilation for certain methods, but this also requires a good code structure, to be able to name the critical methods for the JIT compiler configuration. Afaik, the vector API will stay in incubator state until project Valhalla makes enough progress to be able to improve the fallback’s performance.

Please don't add comments to clarify, [edit] your question instead, so that you can format code blocks and update the code as needed.

In general, if you're not using JMH, it's best to assume performance measurements are made up.
